# Is it possible to load a car logo dataset located in your hard disk and use tensorflow to apply an Image Classification algorithm using that dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am trying to create an Image Classification algorithm (like the one here - https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) using a car logo dataset created by myself and that is stored in my hard disk.
My question is: is it possible to apply the same process used in the link above to a locally stored dataset?

Comment: hows your dataset organized? there is folder for each class and under those folder you store the images?

Comment: Yes, we have a folder for each car brand and, inside each class, there are the car logo images.

Comment: then pass folder directory to the directory argument in tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory function, tell me if its okay otherwise i can make a detailled answer in the answer section

Comment: I tried everything and I didn't get it to work. Can you use the tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory and change the program here -https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/ - so that it works with the image_dataset_from_directory function?

Comment: Yes, If your dataset is stored as same as https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/, you can use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()`. Thanks!